# Using Mac Texture Packer for Cocos2D Android port

Tags: cocos2d-android, texturepacker

I just finished an iPhone game using cocos2d. I used the Texture Packer program to create the texture files I needed for my game. This program created some pvr.ccz compressed files.

Now I want to port the game to Android. I installed the Android SDK and am ready to import the cocos2d-android libraries. But it isn't clear to me if I can use the same pvr.ccz files I created for the iPhone. What exactly do I need to do in Texture Packer to create output files that can be used in a cocs2d-android project?

Please note that I definitely want to use cocos2d-android, since I am porting from iPhone android, so I don't want to switch to libgdx or some other game engine.

Comment: If .pvr.ccz doesn't work, export as PNG. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can now answer my own question. The comment by LearnCocos2D above is correct - I verified this with the Texture Packer folks. Android phones really vary in their support for different types of images, some support PVR and some do not. Most if not all do not support any compressed PVR. But all support PNG. So the best solution is to just use the same Texture Packer project but export to PNG instead of pvr.ccz.

Answer (score 0):

@LearnCocos2D: What about the peak in the run-time memory which pngs cause? Your detailed bog post about memory management in Cocos2D did mention this.

Also, by using PNG, we won't be able to use image formats like PVRTC4/2 which reduce the size a lot.

Any work around for this? Let me know